# Оконный режим в Delphi.

Tags: delphi

Какие функции ввода и вывода используются в оконном режиме Delphi?

Comment: Что за "оконный режим"? Это обычная оконная программа и Вы интересуетесь как ввести в окно (форму), и вывести что-то на это же окно? Так что-ли?

Comment: +1 вот и я не понимаю вопроса. Делфи изначально оконная среда разработки для оконных приложений, ну можно конечно и не оконные, но вопрос сейчас не в этом.

Comment: А можно, более поподробней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция MessageDlg используется для отображения сообщений пользователю. Эти сообщения могут быть информационными, предупреждающими или что бы то ни было. Даётся полный свободный выбор кнопок, которые пользователь может нажать, чтобы подтвердить диалог.

mtWarning - Отображает символ восклицания

mtError - Отображает красный "Х"

mtInformation - Отображает "i" в круге

mtConfirmation - Отображает знак вопроса

mtCustom - Отображает только сообщение

Значение Buttons может быть одним из следующих перечисленных значений:

mbYes - Отображает кнопку "Yes"

mbNo - Отображает кнопку "No"

mbOK - Отображает кнопку "OK"

mbCancel - Отображает кнопку "Cancel"

mbAbort - Отображает кнопку "Abort"

mbRetry - Отображает кнопку "Retry"

mbIgnore - Отображает кнопку "Ignore"

mbAll - Отображает кнопку "All"

mbNoToAll - Отображает кнопку "No to all"

mbYesToAll - Отображает кнопку "Yes to all"

mbHelp - Отображает кнопку "Help"

Пример кода : Показ диалога с подтверждением

```
 var
  buttonSelected : Integer;
 begin
  // Отображение диалога с подтверждением
  buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Confirmation',mtError, mbOKCancel, 0);

  // Показ типа выбранной кнопки
  if buttonSelected = mrOK     then ShowMessage('Была нажата OK');
  if buttonSelected = mrCancel then ShowMessage('Была нажата Cancel');
 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Show Message и MSG DLG ДРУГОЕ